# raphaeljs mouse event bug in opera?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have pretty simple svg: just one rectangle that needs to be animated on hover.

Here's what i have now:

```
var paper = Raphael('paper', 50, 50);

var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 20, 20).attr({
    'width': 20,
    'height': 20,
    'fill': "red",
    'stroke-width': 0,
}).data('x', 'y');


rect.mouseover(function() {
    this.toFront();
    this.animate({
        'transform': 's2'
    }, 70);
}).mouseout(function() {
   this.animate({
      'transform': 's1'
   }, 50);
});​
```

Take a look in action http://jsfiddle.net/HPmqN/

Here's the problem: that code doesn't work correctly in Opera (and IE, i believe), seems like mouseout event just doesn't fired up. Is this some kind of bug in Raphael, Opera or in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a .stop() to each .animate() call in your mouseover() and mouseout() functions as they are bugging each other during the animation

```
rect.mouseover(function() {
    this.toFront();
    this.stop().animate({
        'transform': 's2'
    }, 70);
}).mouseout(function() {
   this.stop().animate({
      'transform': 's1'
   }, 50);
});​
```

Also for the sake of it I would try to make the out and over animation the same time. Just for viewing pleasure. But thats just me.

**Edit:**
Apparently `this.toFront()` is causing Opera to lose track of the DOM element. As you stated that you need the toFront() you could exchange that by using $.css() to achieve the same effect (possibly)

```
$(this).css('zIndex', 9999);
```

Comment: sorry fixed it, as the stop() needs to be in front of the animate

Comment: works in webkit, but, unfortunately, still doesn't work correctly in opera

Comment: Moving things with toFront means removing and inserting the element into the DOM, at which point Opera loses track of what element had focus (not sure if there's a spec that states what should happen with focus when elements are removed from the DOM). Anyway, that's the reason. Avoid doing toFront and it should work.

Comment: yeah, without toFront() it works well, but i kinda need it. So, is there any workarounds?

Comment: instead of toFront() [although Im not sure what this does in particular) you could use the things i put in my edit above